# IBM Worklight - Thumbnail image from project is not updated in Worklight Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-console

[This IBM Worklight Information Center article](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_application_resources.html) mentions that:

> The thumbnail image provides a graphical identification for the
>   application. It must be a square image, preferably of size 128 by 128
>   pixels. It is used to identify the app in the IBM Worklight catalog.
>
> IBM Worklight Studio creates a default thumbnail image on creating the
>   app. Override this default image with an image that matches your
>   application. The file is in the /common/images folder of the app.

I have tried to replace with the default image with my image under common/images/thumbnail.png.

In application-descriptor.xml:
`<thumbnailImage>common/images/thumbnail.png</thumbnailImage>`

However, the thumbnail displayed in Worklight Console remains unchanged.

May I know if the setting `<thumbnailImage>` in application-descriptor.xml equal to the thumbnail displayed in IBM Worklight catalog as mentioned in the Information Center?

Worklight versions:

- Worklight Developer Edition 5.0.6
- Worklight Developer Edition 6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> May I know if the setting  in
>   application-descriptor.xml equal to the thumbnail displayed in IBM
>   Worklight catalog as mentioned Information Center?

Yes. The `thumbnailImage` element in `application-descriptor.xml` allows for changing the thumbnail image displayed in Worklight Console, as mentioned in the IBM Worklight Information Center article you have linked to.

This is a defect in Worklight Console.
Will be fixed.

Thanks.

Comment: @red23jordan, FYI, fixed internally. Feel free to mark as answered.

Comment: @RED.Skull, yes. Are you experiencing otherwise?

Comment: Yeah i am working on this. Now i plan to change directly in Xcode - Resource folder. Is it correct way ?

Comment: What are you talking about... the thumbnailImage is for the worklight console - not the application.

Comment: Sorry my bad wrong understanding. I dont want to change thumbnail instead to change app icon. Okey i will try. Thanks for your response idan