# IBM Worklight - Can't change app icon in both Worklight Console and device

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-console

I want to change the application icon from the default one to custom one.

I'm using this element in application-descriptor.xml

```
<thumbnailImage>common/images/some-logo.png</thumbnailImage>
```

but nothing changes. 
There is still a default image in Worklight Console and iPad, that i deploy to the iOS  Simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `thumbnailImage` element in `application-descriptor.xml` does **not** control the application icon you see in a device/simulator.

- For changing the application icon in Worklight Console, see my answer in this question: [IBM Worklight - Thumbnail image from project is not updated in Worklight Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417685/ibm-worklight-thumbnail-image-from-project-is-not-updated-in-worklight-console).
- For changing the application icon of the application itself, in **iOS**:

  1. Open the `iphone\nativeResources\Resources` folder
  2. Copy your icon(s) to the folder
  3. Right-click on the application folder and choose:

     - Run As >> Build All and Deploy or
     - Run As >> Xcode project (if on Mac)
  4. Build the generated Xcode project in Xcode
  5. Run on device / iOS Simulator

The size and filename of the icon varies depending on which icon you want to change.
Follow Apple's guidelines in this article: [Custom Icon and Image Creation Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1).

Basically, look the naming convention as seen in `iphone\native\Resources` (not to be confused with the other path I mentioned above). Your icon filename must match the name of the existing  icon in order to replace it during the build operation.

Comment: I've already seen that question, the point of that question is that the icon does not appear in the console.

But application icon (on the iPad in my case) is the most important for me.

So you wanna say, that the problem with a console icon is the same like the one with application icon on the mobile device?

Comment: @KenAdams, if the answer satisfies you please mark as Answered. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've just tested it and everything works good!
But could you please clarify, is it a standard way of setting icons, or it's a workaround?

Comment: The standard way would be to change it in Xcode, not in Eclipse. You could place the icons right in the native folder and it would still be OK. But if you would to delete the native folder, they'd be gone. Using the nativeResources then is a sort of a backup. Also useful when using source control systems where you wouldn't usually commit the native folder to.