# iphone app icon doesn't change in Xcode iOS Simulator for iPhone 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using MobileFirst 6.3
I have followed the steps mentioned in [IBM Worklight - Can't change app icon in both Worklight Console and device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611138/ibm-worklight-cant-change-app-icon-in-both-worklight-console-and-device)

I have created an icon of size 120*120,named it as Icon-120.png

Copied it to iphone\nativeResources\Resources

After I run it as an Xcode project , I could see that this icon was copied to iphone\native\Resources

But still the default icon does not change in iOS simulator.

Can someone point out if I missed anything ?

Thanks

Comment: Clean & Rebuild . Remove the App from Simulator . Run . If still can't , Reset Contents & Settings in Simulator menu & retry .

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.Tried all these but still the same issue

Comment: Can you see the App Icon in Image Assets? I think you didn't drag it to the icon placeholder.

Comment: Im sorry to say that I am very new to using Worklight and Xcode.

Comment: I just followed the tutorials and some posts here.I don't know what do you mean by Image Assets and dragging it to icon placeholder

Comment: Have you referenced the Icon-120.png in your xCode project inside the "nativeResources" folder.?, adding the icon to "Resources" doesn't mean that the xCode project will reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following:

- Created Sample WL project.
- Added iPhone Environment.
- native and nativeResources Folder have been created.
- copied the .plist file - .xcodeproj file and Resources folder from "native" folder to "nativeResources" folder.
- Deleted the "native" folder, since it will be generated in the next build.
- added the following icons to "Resources" folder, inside the "nativeResources" :
  (Icon-29 , Icon-57 , Icon-120 , iTunesArtwork.png [ which is 512*512])

[image]

- open .codeproj and make sure the icons are inside.

  [image]
- Build the project from Eclipse after you "Refresh" it. and the new icon should appear.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Hussam. Actually I had to use the Icon-120@2x.png.

Answer (score 0):

add this property in your `.plist` file

[image]

Comment: In iphone\native\myProjName-Info.plist I already had an entry for Icon-120 (without the png extension )